# UWP AdvancedCollectionView sort by DateTime? throws Exception

Tags: c#, sorting, datetime, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

So I have an `AdvancedCollectionView` in my UWP app, tied to an `ObservableCollection`. The `ViewModel` that represents each `Item` in the collection has several properties of types including `string`, `decimal?`, and `DateTime?`.
Everything works great until....I try to add a `SortDescriptor` based on one of the `DateTime?` properties at which time I get a **Failed to compare two elements in the array** exception. The `InnerException` message is the famous **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**.

The Stack Trace on the `InnerException` looks like this:

```
at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.AdvancedCollectionView.System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<System.Object>.Compare(Object x, Object y)
at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.InternalBinarySearch(T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, T value, IComparer`1 comparer)
at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.BinarySearch(T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, T value, IComparer`1 comparer)
```

Here's the code:

```
this.ItemsView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("PurchaseDate", SortDirection.Ascending));
```

Sorting by any of the other property types works fine.  So...what am I doing wrong?

Here's the link to the documentation on the `AdvancedCollectionView`:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/helpers/advancedcollectionview
It contains another link to the Sort documentation but, either it's a placeholder for future documentation or the link is broken.

Comment: You are getting an error because one of the objects is NULL.  A datetime cannot be null so on e of the items in the collection is null.

Comment: @jdweng, `DateTime?` **can** be null.

Comment: Depends on version of Net.

Comment: My initial thought was that this was caused by null values in the specified DateTime? property.  But I would like to mention that sorting by a decimal? property, that I know has quite a few null values, doesn't get an exception.

Also, I checked...and one of the DateTime? properties has 0 null values in the collection.

Comment: To make things even more weird, I put a break point on the getter for property on which I'm sorting and that break point isn't hit before the exception is thrown.

Comment: I have tried with modified official sample and seems to work fine with *DateTime?* and sort description. Can you share a minimal project with the issue?

Comment: I'm an idiot.  The 2 DateTime? properties are defined in a class that inherits from the Items.....The null reference exception is thrown b/c the properties themselves don't exist.